# Is it possible to avoid cases for this question?

Tags: probability

There are ten old cars, six of them manufactured in 1955 and four of them manufactured in 1962. On average the 1955 models will start $65$% of the time and the 1962 models will start $80$% of the time. Find the probability that at any time exactly four of the cars will start.

It seems that cases must be considered but I have seen a similar style question previously that was able to work out the probability that EITHER car starts, then you can apply binomial probability to get the answer in one shot (although it did take time to find the probability that either car starts first). Why is $0.65 \times 0.8$ not valid as this "EITHER" probability?

Comment: When you multiply probabilities it means both events will occur, i.e. both cars will start, not either one.

Answer (score 1):

When you want the probability that at least one event of many will occur, it is easiest to take the complement of the probability that none of the events will occur. If you have one car from each category, the probability neither will start is $(0.35)(0.2)$, so the probability that at least one starts is $1-(0.35)(0.2)$.